# Dreamweaver hangs when opening or viewing a file

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze, crash, dreamweaver

I've scoured the internet for a solution to this but I can't figure it out and no fixes seem to work.

I have a basic .html file attached to a Dreamweaver site, along with some .js, .css and  image files. None of the files are particularly big (they're mainly jQuery and Bootstrap files). The problem is when I start up Dreamweaver and then open a file, it takes around 30 seconds to open the file. I'm using a Pentium Dual Core E2200, 4Gb RAM on 64-bit Windows 8.1 with dual screens. The worse part is that whenever I switch to another window (or even click something other than Dreamweaver) Dreamweaver completely freezes up. It'll stop hanging 2 minutes after trying to focus on it again but it does this every time I switch out of Dreamweaver without fail.

I've tried clearing the cache and setting `ResolveRemoteURLToIPAddress` to `FALSE` but it didn't make the slightest bit of difference.

Also this is my work PC - my Althon II X3/8Gb/Windows 8.1 setup at home has no problems.

Comment: Hi @Dave, thanks for the suggestion. I commented out all of the CSS and JS files and it looks like the Bootstrap files are the problem - they are considerably bigger than most other files (>100k each) but this has never been a problem before - I've built entire websites with Bootstrap without this happening. These are the .min files too.

Comment: They're saved locally - CSS: "/AppResources/css", JS: "/AppResources/JS".

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file in Notepad, and comment out the external links. Then try to load it in Dreamweaver. If it now loads (which based upon the comments on the OP it does), it suggests it's one of the external files. Uncomment them, line at a time until you find the culprit.

Some times, the issue could be a corrupted file, it could be an issue with where the resource is (if it's on a CDN or if it's local). If it's on the CDN or over the wire, is it currently accessible. If it's local, how did you get it there? Did you save a file (and did it save correctly), or did you copy and paste (and did it copy and paste correctly/all content). Maybe easier to just re-download the faulty file or a previous release of the file...

Lastly, make sure you have permission to read the file - if they've saved in a file which you don't have access too from the program it could cause an issue (although I will point out this is probably quite unlikely to be the issue)

Comment: I downloaded these .css and .js files from the official Bootstrap website. I'll download them again in case they were corrupted, but they do appear to be working when I run the .html file in my browser. Thanks!

Comment: Loadign from a CDN seems to do the trick, I just prefer to have the files under my own control rather than rely on CDNs. Thanks for you help @Dave.

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by disabling css rendering in dreamweaver.

- open dreamweaver.
- click on view.
- click style rendering.
- untick display styles.

That solves the issue but you cannot see the live page in the display view unless viewed in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the embedding of a font in the CSS file.

```
 src: url("data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABAAAAACZQABIAAAAAbvQAACXoAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP0ZGVE0cGh4by
```

The solution I did was turn the .css into a .php file like this.

```
<?php
print <<<STYLE
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: "BungeeFont";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABAAAAACZQABIAAAAAbvQAACXoAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP0ZGVE0cGh4byG
```

That way, DW doesn't try to interpret.

Sure wish there was an error message for this type of thing :)